# dplyr::select - using column more than once?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
select(mtcars,foo=mpg,bar=mpg)
```

This will return a data frame with just one column - bar. It appears dplyr discards previous occurrences of a column, making multiple aliases for the same column impossible. Bug? Design? Workaround?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's by design. You could just use `mutate` instead

Comment: I'm actually surprised that it doesn't fail, it's not consistent with the way `mutate` behaves `select(mtcars,foo=mpg,bar=foo)` fails, and as I see it it should be the other way around

Comment: Actually both `transmute(mtcars,foo=mpg,bar=foo)` and `transmute(mtcars,foo=mpg,bar=mpg)` work

Answer (score 1):

workaround: add a mutate that uses foo to create bar.

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(foo = mpg) %>% 
  mutate(bar = foo)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do `transmute(mtcars, foo = mpg, bar = mpg)` (with the caveat that this drops the row names).

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)
map2(c('mpg', 'mpg'), c('foo', 'bar'), ~ mtcars %>% 
          select(!! .y := !! rlang::sym(.x))) %>% 
  bind_cols
```

---

Or another option is `replicate` the `select`ed columns and set the names to the desired one

```
replicate(2, mtcars %>%
                   select(mpg))  %>%
      set_names(c('foo', 'bar')) %>%
      bind_cols
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do

```
mtcars %>% 
  select(foo=mpg) %>% 
  bind_cols(bar=.$foo)
```

or

```
mtcars %>% 
  bind_cols(foo=.$mpg, bar=.$mpg)  
  select(foo, bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why everybody is using `dplyr` for the workaround. Base R is **much faster**:

UPDATED: I wrote `myfun4` and `myfun3` in base R. The former is scalable. The latter isn't. The other four functions are the solutions with `dplyr`. The benchmark shows `dplyr` is slower by more than a factor of ten:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(myfun1(),myfun2(),myfun3(),myfun4(),myfun5(),myfun6())
Unit: microseconds
     expr    min      lq      mean  median       uq     max neval
 myfun1() 5356.6 5739.90  6320.338 5967.45  6327.75 11177.7   100
 myfun2() 6208.1 6676.55  7220.770 6941.10  7172.55 10936.3   100
 myfun3() 8645.3 9299.30 10287.908 9676.30 10312.85 15837.1   100
 myfun4() 4426.1 4712.40  5405.235 4866.65  5245.20 12573.2   100
 myfun5()  168.6  250.05   292.472  270.70   303.15  2119.3   100
 myfun6()  141.7  203.15   341.079  237.00   256.45  6278.0   100
```

The code:

```
myfun6<-function(){
n=2
res_l<-lapply(1:n,function(j) mtcars$mpg)
res<-data.frame(do.call(cbind,res_l))
rownames(res)=rownames(mtcars)
colnames(res)=c('foo','bar')
}

myfun5<-function(){
res<-data.frame(foo=mtcars$mpg,bar=mtcars$mpg)  
}

myfun4<-function(){
  mtcars %>% 
  select(foo=mpg) %>% 
  bind_cols(bar=.$foo)
}

myfun3<-function(){
res<-map2(c('mpg', 'mpg'), c('foo', 'bar'), ~ mtcars %>% 
          select(!! .y := !! rlang::sym(.x))) %>% 
  bind_cols
}

myfun2<-function(){
  res<-transmute(mtcars, foo = mpg, bar = mpg)
}

myfun1<-function(){
  res<-mtcars %>% 
  select(foo = mpg) %>% 
  mutate(bar = foo)
}
```

Comment: While base R is faster, `dplyr` generally leads to cleaner ("tidier") code with improved readability. If you had to maintain somebody else's code, would you rather work with `myfun6` or `myfun2`? I read somewhere that machines will always get faster, but unreadable code will remain unreadable.

Comment: Because this question is _not_ about efficiency, but about whether `dplyr::select` is working as intended. So an appropriate workaround, IMO, would be something that uses `dplyr` functions.

Comment: you got a point there @useR. @ArtemSokolov I mean if readability was the goal, wouldn't you want to force users to deliver their code in something nicer to read in general - like e.g. `python`?

Comment: I don't think microseconds are so important here, but I played anyway, this is faster: `setNames(mtcars[,c("mpg","mpg")],c("foo","bar"))`